# How to know which rows have errors in Pervasive?

Tags: select, pervasive

I have to execute a query on *Pervasive*  but some rows have wrong data, and I'm getting *"Error row"-msg*, if I exclude the rows with errors the query works well, but I have some cases when the number of fields is so huge and I can't know exactly which row has the errors.
I checked the log but doesn't say nothing interesting 
I want to know if exist some statement for check that or any tool that can helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the message?  Is it one field that is causing the error?  Without knowing what kind of error or row that's failing, it's going to be hard to filter it out.  What tool are you using?  What happens if you run the same query in the Pervasive Control Center?

Comment: The message is"Numeric Value Out Of Range", i convert the columns that was causing the error. They was real and I changed them to long var char now I know the rows but Ii would like to know is is any other way to know it   when the query is being execute. Thanks.

Comment: Ideally, you would fix the data.   You should be able to use an IF and the IsNumeric functions in your query depending on the version of PSQL you're using.